# Tradução: localização ou internacionalização?

Tags: debate, tradução, meta-tags

Should we be sub-tagging the [tradução](/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) questions as either [localização](/questions/tagged/localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o) or [internacionalização](/questions/tagged/internacionaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)?

We could use [localização](/questions/tagged/localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o) for issues with the Portuguese translation and [internacionalização](/questions/tagged/internacionaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o) for strings we did not translate yet.

What do you say?

---

Deveriamos fazer um re-tag nas questões de [tradução](/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) como [localização](/questions/tagged/localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o) ou [internacionalização](/questions/tagged/internacionaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)?

Podemos usar [localização](/questions/tagged/localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o) para problemas com a tradução do Português e [internacionalização](/questions/tagged/internacionaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o) para textos que ainda não traduzimos.

O que vocês dizem?

Comment: Makes sense. Then we could perhaps drop `tradução`, it would be redundant

Comment: Agree. They are indeed different issues. Btw, typo: `internationalização` -> `internacionalização`

Comment: That suggestion is also very helpful for you DEVs, you can sort out pressing issues quicker (internationalization) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Português

**Concordo com a ideia**, sempre nos permite criar uma separação entre os dois maiores tópicos referentes a traduções.

Com uma tag adicional, mais facilmente sabemos se estamos a falar de um problema relacionado com uma tradução existente em português, ou se estamos a referir-nos a um assunto que ainda não foi internacionalizado.

[tradução](/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) + [localização](/questions/tagged/localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Dir-nos-á que o assunto refere-se a algo já em Português mas que carece atenção.

[tradução](/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) + [internacionalização](/questions/tagged/internacionaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Dir-nos-á que o assunto refere-se a algo que ainda está a ser visto em Inglês.

---

## English

**I agreed with this ideia**, it allows us to have a distinct separation between the two major translation issues.

With the usage of an aditional tag, we will have a quicker way to identify the subject since it may concern an issue with an already translated text or an issue with a text that still awaits to become internationalized.

[tradução](/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) + [localização](/questions/tagged/localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

It will tell us that the issue regards something that's already translated to Portuguese but requires atention.

[tradução](/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) + [internacionalização](/questions/tagged/internacionaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

It will tell us that the issue concerns *something* that still appears in English rather than internationalized.